# How to "convert" processor/chipset name to /proc/cpuinfo output?

Tags: cpu, chipset

I'm trying to choose a laptop and see "Chipset" and "CPU" being listed as a codename.

Sometimes there is an article in Wikipedia about the processor or chipset mentioning it's features, sometimes not.

How to know in advance what "cat /proc/cpuinfo" will output (i.e. what features the processor will exactly support) without actually buying the device?

For example, how to know in advance if hardware is capable for video adapter pass-thought into KVM virtual machine?

Comment: Look up the CPU and chipset on the manufacturers site. For passthough devices you usually need VT-d ([intel](ark.intel.com)) or AMD-Vi.

Comment: Does laptops in general support AMD-Vi? Or it is only for "Serious" computers?

Comment: I do not dare to answer that with a "Yes, always" or "No, never". *Some* do, some do not. You need a CPU which supports it (see this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IOMMU-supporting_hardware ), a BIOS which can enable it and possibly chipset support. And most laptops have a quite feature poor BIOS.

Comment: Probably it just can't be done... ["Forget in on a laptop, for now. It does not run out-of-the-box on an average desktop, will be much tricky on a laptop."](http://xen.1045712.n5.nabble.com/Xen-on-a-laptop-td5709259.html)